# How to read n lines above the matched string in perl?

Tags: perl, scripting

Say I have a file xx.txt and it contains the data

```
1 I am here

2 to work in 

3 Perl for writing

4 a script for 

5 myself
```

Suppose i want to search for string script and want to display the three
lines above it , what should i do ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use an array as your print buffer.

```
my @array;
while (<DATA>) {
    push @array, $_;
    shift @array if @array > 4;
    print @array if /script/;
}


__DATA__
1 I am here
2 to work in 
3 Perl for writing
4 a script for 
5 myself
```

**Various usage:**

If you intend to use this as a stand-alone, you might consider using `grep` instead:

```
grep -B3 script xx.txt
```

Or perl one-liner if `grep` is not an option (e.g. you're on Windows):

```
perl -nwe 'push @a, $_; shift @a if @a > 4; print @a if /script/' xx.txt
```

If it is inside a script, you only need to supply your own file handle:

```
my @array;
open my $fh, '<', "xx.txt" or die $!

while (<$fh>) {
    push @array, $_;
    shift @array if @array > 4;
    print @array if /script/;
}
```

Comment: data is a file handler here ?

Comment: I dont know the line number of word to be matched .... thats the issue .. so what should i do ?

Comment: `DATA` can be used within a script to refer to data below the `__DATA__` tag inside the script. You can replace it with a regular file handle, or you can use `<>` to use stdin or `@ARGV`. It all depends on what you are trying to do.

Comment: i am getting syntax error at line 4 and line 8 around while loop

Comment: one thing TLP if i want to store the array contents into variable , what should i do ?

Comment: Just store it. You could do `if (/script/) { @store = @array }`

Comment: @kanwarpal Don't forget that you can mark this answer as accepted by clicking the checkmark to the left.