# How to copy the contents of array into a single variable in Perl?

Tags: perl

I have a data in an array as below. I want to copy all the content in a single variable. How can I do this ?

```
IFLADK
FJ
FAILED
FNKS
FKJ
FAILED
```

Comment: What have you tried? What is the single variable supposed to contain/look like?

Comment: Follow-up question to http://stackoverflow.com/q/9329501/725418

Comment: An array is already a single variable. :)

Comment: I want to say a single scalar variable other than array :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With reference to previous question [How to read n lines above the matched string in perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9329501/725418) Storing multiple hits in an array:

```
while (<$fh>) {
    push @array, $_;
    shift @array if @array > 4;
    if (/script/) {
        print @array; 
        push @found, join "", @array;   # <----- this line
    }
}
```

You could just use a scalar, e.g. `$found = join "", @array`, but then you would only store the last match in the loop.

Suppose the loop is finished, and now you have all the matches in array `@found`. If you want them in a scalar, just join again:

```
my $found = join "", @found;
```

Or you can just add them all at once in the loop:

```
$found .= join "", @array;
```

It all depends on what you intend to do with the data. Having the data in a scalar is rarely more beneficial than having it in an array. For example, if you are going to print it, there is no difference, as `print $found` is equivalent to `print @found`, because `print` takes a list of arguments.

If your intent is to interpolate the matches into a string:

```
print "Found matches: $found";
print "Found matches: ", @found;
```

Comment: Thanks TLP , But i want to store all matches in a scalar $ found , is it possible ?

Comment: @kanwarpal In perl, most anything is possible. The question is most often "What is the best way?" I will update the question with some alternatives.

Comment: TLP Thanks again , will be waiting for your answer :)

Comment: @kanwarpal This is pretty basic stuff. If you don't know your way around perl variables, you won't be able to write even the simplest scripts. So my advice is that you study the perl docs.

Answer (score 4):

You could assign a reference to the array

```
my $scalar = \@array;
```

… or join all the strings in the array together

```
my $scalar = join "\n", @array;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$whole = join(' ', @lines)
```

But if you're reading the text from a file, it's easier to just read it all in one chunk, by (locally) undefining the record delimiter:

```
local $/ = undef;
$whole = <FILE>
```

Comment: It's better to use a proper CPAN module. `File::Slurp` has `read_file()`

Comment: You have to define "better". Sometimes an extra module is not "better".

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what you are trying to do, but if you are wanting to package up an array into a scalar so that it can be retrieved later, then you might want [Storable](https://metacpan.org/module/Storable).

```
use Storable;

my @array = qw{foo bar baz};

my $stored_array = freeze \@array;

...

my @retrieved_array = @{ thaw($stored_array) };
```

Then again it could be that your needs may be served by just storing a reference to the array.

```
my @array = qw{foo bar baz};

my $stored_array = \@array;

...

my @retrieved_array = @$stored_array;
```